# What happens when an electromagnetic wave passes through a magnet or charged capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

What are the effects or interactions between propagating electromagnetic wave that passes through static magnetic field (big neodymium magnet) or static electric field (charged plates of HV capacitor)?? EM wave would bounce off? slow down? or speed up?

Comment: By the linearity of Maxwell's equations, nothing!

Comment: While I agree with the other responses, it's not trivial if you are talking about the interaction of the wave with the matter that forms the magnet or the capacitor. Those are not trivial and you can spend a lifetime researching them, the latest in that line of research are so called "meta-materials", which have very interesting properties that are far from fully explored.

Answer (score 2):

The oscillating fields of the electromagnetic wave just add linearly with the static electric or magnetic fields. Nothing much happens really, and the wave goes on its merry way.

Comment: yet I can turn on mosfet near coil(or move test charge) that has emf around it and compass will experience force so if EM wave consist of both oscillating electric and magnetic elements there should be interaction - adding linearly means  that during the exact moment when wave passes through magnet/charged plate an amplification happens of magnet/electrostatic field strength ? I'm talking here  about very low frequency.